# Can an eclipse cause bad to certain Horoscope signs

Tags: gods, eclipse, evil, horoscopes

I recently saw a video in which few horoscope signs and birth stars are warned before a lunar eclipse, That this lunar eclipse might cause great problem to them? Is it mentioned that lunar and solar eclipses can cause troubles? How should one be safe during such eclipses?

Comment: Yes even I've seen many astrologers say that how a particular eclipse is good for some and bad for some....I wonder how they calculate and predict this  . Even I want to know this.